# Twenty twelve header image and navigation in same line

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can you put the navigation in the same line as the header image in twenty twelve? 
Right now the navigation menu is above the image, but I would like them to be next to each other.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add "position:relative" to #masthead:

```
#masthead {position: relative;}
```

then position your navigation with position absolute:

```
#site-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* or top, if you prefer */
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: One more thing. It seems that if I do this, the Header image is slightly more to the top compared to the navigation... Why is that?

Comment: The header may have some padding, or the image some space around. All you need to do is change the bottom:0 to bottom:10px, or whatever number that gives you the desired effect.

Comment: To find out for sure where is the space coming from, use firebug.