# Move menu up next to logo in Twenty Twelve child theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm doing my first WordPress child theme based on the Twenty Twelve theme, and I want to move my menu up next to my header logo...

Below is an example of how it looks now, and what I want to achieve... The blue box represents the header logo, and I want my menu to appear to the right of it...

[image: Example]

My current CSS for the menu is:

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu, .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-align: right;
    color: #656565;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;   
}
```

I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199046/twenty-twelve-header-image-and-navigation-in-same-line) which is regarding the same, but when I use the proposed solution from it, my menu is suddenly way down on my site below a post...

Answer (score 1):

Well, got it to work by placing the position style in #site-navigation instead of my previous code and then playing around with the values (using top instead of bottom)

Answer (score 1):

You also may look into changing the tag "nav" display style in the stylesheet.css file:

```
nav {
    display: block;
}
```

Try inline-block or inline.

Answer (score 1):

```
#masthead hgroup {float: left;}
nav#site-navigation {float: right; width: 500px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#masthead {position: relative;}

#site-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* or top, if you prefer */
    right: 0;
}
```